# Ruby not iterating through an array that has one element

Tags: ruby

Here is my loop

```
 subscriptions.each do |s|
     if s.is_active? && s.is_current?
        #do some stuff
     end
  end
```

subscriptions is an array that has one element. However it does not hit the if statement inside the loop.

When I step through it using rdebug I get this

```
(rdb:1748) p subscriptions.count
1
```

I am on ruby version 1.8.7

Am I missing something?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What about `subscriptions.length`? How are you sure that it's never stepping into the block?

Comment: Put here the content of subscriptions by printing the "puts subscriptions.inspect".

Comment: `puts subscriptions.select{ |s| s.is_active? && s.is_current? }.length`

Comment: @ChrisHeald subscriptions.length returns 1 also. I know that it is not going into the block because I am using ruby-debug to step through the code.  I see it skip the block and go on to some code that is past this loop.

Comment: @Kyle hmmm... interesting.  That returns 0.  Never used select before, I assume it selects all elements that meet the condition.  This has me thinking.  Off to investigate!

Comment: @kjennings.dev You're correct. It basically filters the array to only the elements that met your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Check if it works?

```
subscriptions.each { |s| puts s }
```

If above code prints your elements, then there is some issue with your condition i.e. below code is not proper:

```
if s.is_active? && s.is_current?
  #do some stuff
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being Case sensitivity on some data in the DB. All is good now. It is peculiar that it seemed to have skipped the block, but I am sure it is my own ignorance of how ruby-debug works. I am after all relatively new to ruby/rails development. Thanks all!

Comment: Did you use `next` rather than `step`? `next` will not descend into functions, whereas `step` will. A block is basically an anonymous function.

Comment: I was using next. Amazing help!